# Gradle dist/bin/script fileMode

Tags: gradle

Using Gradle to build an application, I created a "src/dist/bin" folder for a shutdown.sh script to be packaged in the distribution zip. How can I set the fileMode so it can be executed? I already know how to set the fileMode using the copy task but in that case the script is copied by the distribution plugin.

[Gradle Application plugin](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html)

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide sample `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be the same as in any Copy Task because distribution is using [CopySpec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html). I use code similar to the following. I put the scripts to a different folder.

```
distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            into('bin') {
                from {
                    'src/main/customscripts/start.sh'
                }
                fileMode 0755
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works and I had to move the script location because if I kept it in the "src/dist/bin" folder it's included twice in the distribution tar file. Verify it with Gradle version 2.4.

Comment: It needs `duplicatesStrategy = 'exclude'` too, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489384/gradle-creating-duplicate-start-scripts-into-bin-directory

Comment: ...and as I've discovered since, `fileMode` only works for me if I avoid using `duplicatesStrategy` because it is the second copy that has the correct `fileMode` and yet this copy is the one that gets deleted if I use `duplicatesStrategy`.

Comment: Will this work even if you build on a Windows machine?

Comment: @KarlIvarDahl yes, in fact I use it because the build happens on a Windows machine